# Java android xml textbox has no text = no button hit

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a problem here.
I need it so if there is no text in Either of my 2 textboxes that you wont beable to hit the button

my JAVA code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.teachme);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    Button teach = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_teach_send);
    teach.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.btn_teach_send:
        {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://monaiz.net/get.php");

            String responseStr = "";

            try {
                TextView word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_teach_request);
                TextView answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_teach_response);

                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("word", word.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", answer.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "teach"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity( );

                responseStr = EntityUtils.toString( entity );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

            if( responseStr.equals("ok") )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Poka just learned a new word!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    this.finish();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And then this is my xml code which is obv for the design of the app..

the button and the edit text stuff is in there

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

    <ScrollView android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true" android:isScrollContainer="true">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll_teach" android:background="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip" android:layout_weight="0.0">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="50.0dip" android:src="@drawable/if_ask" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.0">

                    <EditText android:gravity="top|left|center" android:maxLength="30" android:id="@+id/tv_teach_request" android:background="@drawable/mespeak" android:paddingLeft="23.0dip" android:paddingTop="6.0dip" android:paddingRight="28.0dip" android:paddingBottom="23.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" style="@style/TeachBubbleFont" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip" android:layout_weight="0.0">
                <ImageView android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="40.0dip" android:src="@drawable/then_response" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <EditText android:gravity="top|left|center" android:maxLength="30" android:id="@+id/tv_teach_response" android:background="@drawable/pokaspeak" android:paddingLeft="28.0dip" android:paddingTop="6.0dip" android:paddingRight="23.0dip" android:paddingBottom="23.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" style="@style/TeachBubbleFont" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutBtn" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.0">
                <Button android:id="@+id/btn_teach_send" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="35.0dip" android:text="@string/btn_teach_send" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there may be some problem, in xml you are using edit text and in java file you are taking text view. apart from that can't u check simply from getText() method that respective edit text are empty or not. and set button to setClickable(false).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to setenabled property of the button for this. If two textbox has no text then disable button and if they have text then enable button.

Here's example

```
String str1, str2;

str1 = word.getText().toString();
str2 = answer.getText().toString();

if(!(str1.equals("")) && !(str2.equals("")))
{
  teach.setEnabled(true);
}
else
{
  teach.setEnabled(false);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check as soon as any of edittext get changed then you need to use textchangelistner for that.

Here I made small example for it. It enables button only when 2 edittext have any of text.
Hope this will help you.

```
public class TSActivity extends Activity {

     String str = "";
     String str1 = "";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        btn.setEnabled(false);


        txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                str = s.toString();
                if( !(str.equals("")) && !(str1.equals("")) )
                {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
 /**************************************************************************************************/       
        txt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                str1 = s.toString();
                if( !(str.equals("")) && !(str1.equals("")) )
                {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, it works but how do i make it where it keeps checking for it?

Comment: I put it in the oncreate method but it will auto disable it and then when there is text in both of them it wont re-enable it

Comment: Refer my Edit. I've post working example exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

From which source the edittext values will be set.It depends on that if edittext values are getting from any action in that particular listener call the above function.If edittext values you are setting from any function call that function make that function return type as boolean according to true or false call the above steps with in oncreate.